# VMWare 6.x on Vista 64 runs as *32 task

Tags: vmware, vista64, taskmanager

I am trying to run VMWare Workstation 6.5.1 on Vista 64.  It runs, but always as a *32 task.  It is supposed to run as a native 64 bit task.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled with no change.  Any ideas?

Machine is a ASUS P5K, Intel Q6600 cpu, 8 GB RAM.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running 6.5.1 on Windows 2008 64bit and it is also running as *32.

Answer (score 2):

VMWare runs as a 32 bit task, but can still run 64 bit applications if you are running on hardware the supports the VT extensions.  It can also access more than 4GB of memory because it plays a lot of tricks in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is "supposed" to do, but mine runs the same as yours. Haven't had any problems with it either - in fact I am totally impressed with it having had it for just 2 weeks now. Amazing product.

Answer (score 0):

I have a collegue with a very similar configuration, vista 64, vmware workstation 6.5.  His VMS run as native 64 bit tasks in taskman.   I have also seen other threads on the net that complain of the same issue.  It appears that vmware workstation can indeed run as a native 64bit task and that there is a noticable performance difference yet no one seems to know how or why it sometimes runs as *32.